# Serial communication problem with sim7600 with Arduino Mega

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I am just sending the AT command to test if the serial communication works, the response I am getting is a flipped "?" or a square or rectangle symbol.

I have tested the communication using software provided by Waveshare connected through on board USB to UART.

https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM7600E-H_4G_HAT

```
int PowerKey = 2;
char answer;

void setup() 
{
 Serial3.begin(96u00);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(PowerKey, OUTPUT);
 Serial.println("initializing");
 digitalWrite(PowerKey, HIGH);
 delay(1000);
 digitalWrite(PowerKey, LOW);
}

void loop() 
{
  answer = send_at_cmd("AT\r\n");
  Serial.println(answer);
}


uint8_t send_at_cmd(const char* ATcommand)
{
  char response;
  // send test command AT
  Serial3.print(ATcommand);
  Serial.println(ATcommand);
  delay(1000);
  //Check for response from the sim7600E-H
  while(Serial3.available() != 0)
  {
    response = Serial3.read();
  }
  return response;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code sets serial 3 to 9600, but the second image sets the serial port to 115K.  I think that may be a problem, because at least one is wrong.

Comment: I have set it to 115200 but I still have the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have change baud rate by at+iprex=9600 before upload your code, because sim7600 set 115200 by default then save your setting by at&w.

hope this help someone.